# Why is non-negative matrix factorization better than ICA in neuronal analysis

Tags: non-negative-matrix-factorization, independent-component-analysis, neuroscience

I've recently joined a neuroscience lab and am currently reading up on their pipeline to analyze 2-photon [calcium imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_imaging) with single neuron resolution. The data consist of a movie where the pixel values of each frame are proportional to the calcium activity. To analyze this data, we need to locate the position of the neurons and extract their calcium traces. To do this, my lab uses an algorithm called constrained non-negative matrix factorization (CNMF).

In the [paper](https://www.cell.com/neuron/pdfExtended/S0896-6273(15)01084-3) that introduced CNMF for analysis of neuronal calcium data they start by describing some earlier algorithms used for analysis:

> spatiotemporal calcium activity can be approximated as a product of
> two matrices: a spatial matrix that encodes the location of
> each neuron in the optical field, and a temporal matrix that characterizes the calcium concentration evolution of each neuron.
> Based on this observation Mukamel et al. (2009) proposed an Independent Component Analysis (ICA) approach that seeks
> spatiotemporal components that have reduced dependence.
> ...... ICA is an inherently
> linear demixing method and can fail in practice when no linear
> demixing matrix is available to produce independent outputs,
> as is often the case when the neural components exhibit significant spatial overlap.

I kind of understand this reasoning, however, they continue to write:

> The PCA/ICA method searches for a matrix of linear spatial filters such that, when these filters are applied to the video data, the output time series are as independent as
> possible. However, in the case of significant spatial overlap, there is no such linear demixing matrix that can lead to independent outputs, and therefore in this example the PCA/ICA method tends to infer non-overlapping spatial filters (yellow contour plots
> in Figure 2A) by assigning pixels that should belong to both neurons to only one of the neurons......The NMF[Non-negative matrix factorization] method
> proposed in Maruyama et al. (2014) is a nonlinear demixing
> method and can therefore better handle spatially overlapping
> signals, especially in high-SNR conditions.

Here I am significantly more confused, why is the NMF method non-linear? Furthermore, why does the non-linearity help in distinguishing spatially overlapping neurons?